# How can I back up to (or install) Ubuntu 16.04.1 (CUDA 8.0 requirement)

Tags: 16.04, cuda

I currently have 16.04.3 installed with kernel 4.10.0-40-generic, but I would like to install CUDA 8.0. From experience with other machines, I believe that one cannot install the official CUDA 8.0 (from the NVIDIA web site) when using kernels 4.8 or 4.10. However, I know that it can be installed with Ubuntu kernel 4.4. I need CUDA 8.0 because later versions don't support my M2090 GPUs. Unfortunately, the Ubuntu web site does not provide an option to download 16.04.1. Is there any way I can get back to kernel 4.4? Any guidance (or corrections to my statements above) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After more research I came up with a possible solution (still using kernel 4.10). I noticed that the CUDA 9.1 documentation says the 9.1 Toolkit doesn't support Compute Capability 2.0 (e.g., the M2090), but the 9.1 driver does. So I installed the 9.1 driver alone, and it did indeed install successfully. Then I installed the CUDA 8.0 Toolkit sans driver. I haven't tried compiling yet, but a program compiled on another computer (using CUDA 8.0) is running on this computer now.